# VBA autofill functions/variables while typing code

Tags: vba, excel

I get used to C++/C# environment where you type code and functions/variables can be inserted by selecting them by "TAB".

On daily basis I work on excel/access and atm I'm working on big project. My class module has around 100 variables, mostly strings. Is there any option in VBA to auto fill or suggest variable within class module while writing code? For example:

`CurrentWB.Sheets(PDSheet).Select`

CurrentWB is set for Workbooks. After dot it doesn't suggest `Sheets` and after typing brackets it doesn't suggest `PDSheet` and so on.

Any advise is helfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any advise is helpful

1-

Always use `Option Explicit` and `Dim` your variables explicitly

```
Dim CurrentWB as Workbook ' Will make the WB methods appear after typing `CurrentWB.`
```

On the other hand, when you `Dim CurrentWB as Object` or `As Variant` (the Variant case is implictly used when you don't use `Option Explicit`), no intellisense will be available.

2-

In order to have intellisense on variable names, again if you `Dim` your variables, when you type the firts part of the variable name then you type `Ctrl+Space`, intellisense will automatically complete it for you if the entered part is unambiguous, or it will prompt show you the possible suggestions.